# Drag-fill in Infragistics XamDataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I got the requirement to implement this excel-like feature in the existing `xamDataGrid` in the application. For those who don't know what it is, they want to drag a cell (using rclick) and by doing so copy original cell value across the selected cells. Before I start digging in the code, maybe I can save myself some trouble.

1. Is the feature maybe available "out-of-the-box" for xamDataGrid? I couldn't find anything in docs or the web, but maybe I searched wrong.
2. If not, any recommendation on how this would be doable by custom code.

I am still rather new to xamDataGrid object model and requirement is rather urgent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag fill behavior for the XamDataGrid would be a feature request as it isn't built into the control.  For this you should reach out to Infragistics through either the forums or a support case.  You can find links to each from the get help page:
http://www.infragistics.com/support/get-help.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I need something cooked up rather fast. Anyway, I think I am on to something, I'll post it here when done.

Comment: I've solved it using a combination of Mouse Up/Down events. On click I would locate the `CellValuePresenter` visual parent and use it to drill into row, field and cell for initial values, then as the mouse moves to other cells I just copy over.